# Calling mysql stored function - only if it exists

Tags: mysql

How can I do this in MySQL?

> SELECT IF( function_exists(myFunction) , myFunction(...) , false) AS result

Comment: only way I can think to do this is to use system tables to determine existance, and then execute the query if it does exist.

Comment: Look at this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/567/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-procedure-or-function-exists-in-a-mysql-database